# Facebook canvas app with rails3

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, facebook-canvas

I'm writing facebook canvas application with Rails3 using omniauth-facebook gem. The few moments are not clear:

1. Rdirect after sing in (in '/auth/facebook/callback' => 'session#create'):
   After successful sing_in if user is redirected to root_url it *sometime* arrives to 
   my canvas page URL (http://localhost:3000) outside of the frame. On other hand, when 
   redirecting him to my app url (http://apps.facebook.com/my_app) it *sometime* stacks on 
   blank page inside the frame. So **how to handle this redirect correctly?**
2. **What is a proper way to link between pages inside my app?** Currently I use relative links and top.location url is always stay my app url (http://apps.facebook.com/my_app). But I saw that many facebook apps redirect the client top.location (http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/internal_link)... It raises one more question:
3. Now facebook always fetch my app into the iframe using POST method. **How to handle this behavior in RESTful rails application?**

I'd very thankful for any advices...